# Merging several pandas.DataFrames with specific constraints

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Lets say I have 3 different pandas dataFrames

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [20016, 50048, 13478, 68493, 57483],
                         'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M'], 
                         'Var1': [3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                         'Var2': [2, 3, np.nan, 3, 2],
                         'Var3': [-0.25, 0, 4, np.nan, 0.14]})
>>> df1.set_index('ID')

      Sex  Var1  Var2  Var3
ID                         
20016   F     3   2.0 -0.25
50048   M     3   3.0  0.00
13478   F     3   NaN  4.00
68493   F     3   3.0   NaN
57483   M     2   2.0  0.14
```

The 2nd DF is basically an updated version of DF1, which means more row entries and also other columns and maybe changed values in some of the other columns e.g

```
>>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'PERSID': [20016, 50048, 13478, 68493, 57483, 45623],
                             'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M'], 
                             'Var1': [3, *1*, 3, 3, 2, np.nan],
                             'Var2': [*3*, 3, np.nan, 3, 2, 0],
                             'Var3': [-0.25, 0, 4, np.nan, 0.14, 0.28]})
>>> df2.set_index('ID')

       Sex  Var1  Var2  Var3
PERSID                      
20016    F   3.0   3.0 -0.25
50048    M   1.0   3.0  0.00
13478    F   3.0   NaN  4.00
68493    F   3.0   3.0   NaN
57483    M   2.0   2.0  0.14
45623    M   NaN   0.0  0.28
```

And the last dataFrame as an example should be rather different with something like:

```
   SUBJECT         Var4    Var5      Var6
200            1640.345   345.0 -0.250000
6700          14236.430  1713.0 -0.050735
6702           1345.400     NaN  0.034450
1330__201805    345.750   335.0  0.140000
4786__201805        NaN     0.0       NaN
```

And the goal is to merge all 3 dataFrames into one, containing all non redundant information. This means:

1. if there is a new ID simply add the row
2. if there is a new column add the column
3. if there are the exact IDs in two different DFs they need to be merged in such a way that if the cell content is the same, the content of the 2nd DF can be neglected. If however, the content of the cell is different, a new column needs to be added with columnName.y and the other column needs to be renamed to columnName.x

considering only merging of DF1 and DF2 it should look something like this:

```
     ID Sex_x  Var1_x  Var2_x    Var3  Var1_y  Var2_y
  20016     F     3.0     2.0   -0.25     NaN     3.0
  50048     M     3.0     3.0    0.00     1.0     NaN
  13478     F     3.0     NaN    4.00     NaN     NaN
  68493     F     3.0     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
  57483     M     2.0     2.0    0.14     NaN     NaN
  45623     M     NaN     NaN    0.28     NaN     0.0
```

The 3rd DF should then be merged too which would result in basibally only adding the rows and columns. 
All cells which are not present in the other DFs should be filled with NaN

and it would be awesome if the corresponding columns like name.x and name.y would be next to each other to ensure readability.

I have tried things like pandas.DataFrame.(Merge, join, and concatenate), trying to do it by hand but nothing works as it needs to be.

This is an example how I did the adding of the columns if they are not present:

```
df_combined = df_1.copy()
for ind, column in enumerate(df_2):
    if not column in list(df_combined):
        df_combined.insert(len(df_combined.columns), column,
                           value=pd.Series(np.nan),
                           allow_duplicates=False)

frame = [df_combined, df_2]
    df_combined = pd.concat(frame)
```

which is probably already not a good solution.

Thanks for any help on how to implement this!

Comment: Lots of examples and explanation are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html
Perhaps show us how far that gets you.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the guide I meant within my post. Basically I started to work with DataFrames with this project and I spent already more than a week working on this. 
I've figured out how to do parts of my task with this guide but combining all needs in one is bugging me  -  but I'll try to go over the guide once more ...

Comment: I made a mistake in my wanted solution and have edited the question. 
Moreover, I am wondering why for df2 the values of Var1 are integers while the ones from df1 are integers ?
I suppose it's because of the np.nan value - right?